# AsyncTask running two different thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i am wondering is that possible (best practice) to run two long running query in two different thread using AsyncTask?

my scenario is something like this:

```
1) Loading data from HttpGet (once it load then load into the listview)
2) Parsing the data into Listview
```

currently, i am running the `doInBackground` to do the #1 and on `onPostExecute` doing the #2
the response is okay but i am thinking is there a way i can make it more faster?

if i go with running two different thread but the question is, will i be able to run another thread (AsyncTask) from `onPostExecute`?

Thanks,

Comment: Why not use the same `AsyncTask` to do both and return from `doInBackground` only the final data for the `ListView`?

Comment: yes i did try but i get the error message saying can not run two thread in one (something similar to that) i don't have exact error message since i have shuffle my code around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether it will be any faster, because if you think about it the steps are kinda serial, you need the data retrieval first, followed by parsing and then showing the data in listview.

So the AsyncTask would only help u in avoiding the ANR. You can always do ure parsing in another AsyncTask. But it wont make the whole cycle any faster.

Answer (score 0):

When you start an AsyncTask you have two threads running in your application. The UI thread and the AsyncTask thread.

Do the long running operations in one AsyncTask. Getting/parsing the data should be done inside doInBackground. onPostExceute is invoked from the UI thread which is the only place you should be updating your ListView from.

You can start another AsyncTask from onPostExecute but it will be called after your doBackground finishes.

To run two tasks in parallel, invoke two AsyncTasks at the same time from the UI thread.